# Write $f\in S(X)$ as a composition of $g,h\in S(X)$ such that $g$ and $h$ are of order $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on a group theory exercise in which I have to show that any function in $S(X)$, the group of all bijective functions mapping $X$ to itself, can be written as the composition of two functions of order $2$, that is, functions being their own inverse. Here is $X$ is assumed to be an infinite set. In the first part I managed to show this is true for the group of congruences of $\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping the origin onto itself. However, I have no idea what to do here, since I dit not manage to find any decomposition that seems to work. Any help/hint is much appreciated!

Comment: So $\;S(X)\;$ is **not** the bijective functions with finite support, but rather **all** the bijective functions $\;X\to X\;$ .

Comment: Yes indeed, that is just the definition of $S(X)$ right?

Comment: [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871783/every-permutation-is-a-product-of-two-permutations-of-order-2)