# Finding an order-2 permutation that sorts colored balls

Tags: permutations, modular-arithmetic, coloring, sorting

> Suppose there are $M$ different colors of ball and you have $N$ of each kind. You arrange all of the balls in an arbitrary linear order. Is it always possible to find a permutation of order 2 such that no ball shares a color with its neighbor?

(Note: a permutation of order 2 is a permutation which is its own inverse.)

If you only have one color $(M=1)$, then excluding the trivial one-ball case, it's impossible. If you have two colors $(M=2)$, it's always possible: supposing the colors are black and white, just swap every black ball in an odd-numbered position with a white ball in an even-numbered position.

The case for $M>2$ colors seems tricky to me, because the available moves (permutation) and success condition (no same-color neighbors) seem incomparable. I have tried extending the above $M=2$ strategy to greater numbers of colors without much success (e.g. considering index mod $M$, or trying to interleave pairs of colors.)  I have also tried to represent the list of colored balls as integers mod $M$, or even the differences between neighboring balls as integers mod $M$; then, swaps affect the difference list in a particular way.

I have tried representing the list of balls as  a matrix $A$, where $A_{i,j}$ is the number of balls of color $i$ in a position that is equal to $j\pmod{M}$; then, the sums of the rows and columns are all $N$, and one special way of achieving the desired condition is if the colors are all interleaved so that the matrix becomes a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: `Is it always possible to find a permutation of order 2 such that no ball shares a color with its neighbor?` in the last part you listed a matrix of all solutions, you want all permutations or just a valid one ?

Comment: @Abra001 Oops my example was incorrect; deleted. I would like to know if for every $M>2$ and $N$ and arrangement of balls, it is possible to find a permutation of order 2 such that no ball shares a color with its neighbor.

Comment: Intuitively, it must be possible because $M \gt 2$ "has got to be" easier than $M=2$.  For even $M$ it is easy-just make every odd color black, every even color white and apply your proof for $M=2$

Comment: There is something here i couldn't wrap up, you said "is it possible to find a permutation of order 2", [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871783/every-permutation-is-a-product-of-two-permutations-of-order-2) you see that every permutation can be constructed from two deterministic ones of order-2 , or i may be missing something ?

Comment: @Abra001. You want exactly one list permutation of order 2 that exchanges everything. For example, if you have ABCD, you can use a single order 2 permutation to make it BADC, but you can't use a single order 2 permutation to make BDAC. That BDAC permutation isn't order 2 because applying it twice produces DCBA, not the original list.

Comment: @user326210 i know about this, the permutation that produces the second is order 4 (2413) but you could just tell it's a set of disjoint cycles of order-2 permutations, not just (21) or (43) it is (21)(43)

Comment: I don't understand. I am trying to rearrange a list of colored balls so that no neighbors share a color.  If I could use two permutations of order 2, I could make any permutation. But I am trying to use a single permutation of order 2, which might be more difficult.  A single permutation of order 2 is a permutation made up of non-overlapping cycles of length at most 2. It has the property that applying it twice inverts it.

Comment: this is exactly what i meant saying "disjoint" or non-overlapping. it's same.

Comment: Yes, they're the same.  But the permutation ABCD->BADC is the permutation (21)(43). It's a permutation of order 2, and is allowed. The permutation ABCD->BDAC is (1342). It's a permutation of order 4, and is not allowed. Even though you can factor it as a composition of permutations of order 2: (21)(43)(32)